# Binding tmux command key to ctrl-\ on mac

Tags: macos, tmux

I'd like to use ctrl-\ as the command key for tmux.

Ctrl-a and ctrl-b conflict with bash and emacs bindings.

```
set-option -g prefix C-\
```

When I start a tmux session, I get:

```
/Users/justin/.tmux.conf: 40: bad key: C-
```

This works perfectly on ubuntu, but not Mac OS Mountain Lion

If this binding won't work on the Mac, any recommendations for the best command binding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably running *tmux* 1.7 on your Mac, but something earlier on your other boxes (the problem is version specific, not platform specific).

In *tmux* 1.7 a backslash at the end of the line is treated as a line continuation (so that you can break up long commands onto multiple lines, as in most shells).

You can use quotes to protect the backslash in a way that is compatible with both versions (the syntax is different depending on whether you prefer single or double quotes):

```
set-option -g prefix 'C-\'
set-option -g prefix "C-\\"
```

Comment: Thanks -- In the meantime I switched to the common C-a binding and switched bash to vi mode so I don't want to hit ctrl-a all the time. So not sure if I'll go back to ctrl-\.